# UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification called BEFORE textViewDidBeginEditing, but AFTER textFieldDidBeginEditing? Why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextview

I have the following observer in my ViewController.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

This view controller also conforms to the UITextFieldDelegate and UITextViewDelegate and implements `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textViewDidBeginEditing`.

Now, here's the weird part.

If you tap on the **UITextField**, the order of calls is `textFieldDidBeginEditing` AND THEN `keyboardWillChangeFrame:`.

If you tap on the **UITextView**, the order of calls is `keyboardWillChangeFrame` AND THEN 'textViewDidBeginEditing'.

Anyone not see a problem with this? Shouldn't text_____DidBeginEditing be called first no matter whether it's a Field or View. Why is this?

It's leading to weird animation issues. I need it to be consistent one way or the other.

Comment: Can I ask you why are you using UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification? I just did.

Comment: @Everton To animate up view to accommodate for the growing the keyboard. My UITextView more or less takes up 90% of the view. When the keyboard comes on screen, I animate up the height of the UITextView to be above the Keyboard. When the keyboard disappears, I animate it back it down.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, and something like the above code for what you are trying to do:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary *info = notification.userInfo;

    CGRect r = [info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    r = [self.view convertRect:r fromView:nil];

    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    double duration = [info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

    /* view changes */

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification instead of UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification.